# Getting frameless React/Electron app title bar to not disappear during scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, electron

I have a basic app with a text editor and a title bar. I don't want scrollbars to appear on the side unless the text editor goes into overflow. Even then, I don't want the titlebar to disappear during the scroll. Right now, it does.

I think there's some CSS witchcraft I'm missing here, or maybe I've done something wrong.

Using React, JS, and Electron. The text editor is [Quill.js](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) if that matters. Used `create-react-app`.

App.css:

```
.App {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.editor {
    background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
    color: rgb(201, 201, 201);
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.app-bar {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

import './App.css';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';

export class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="app-bar">
          test
        </div>
        <div>
          <ReactQuill theme="bubble" className="editor" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Screenshot of what I mean:

[image: image1]

When I scroll down the text stays there, but the colour scrolls:

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

Try add this,

```
body{
margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping out! One minor observation: although your answer may be very obvious to experienced programmers, it would be even better if you add a small explanation on why your solution fixes the issue. Best regards!

Comment: Hey, tried that out and ended up with some weirder styling: https://i.imgur.com/ovTFsHQ.png